# How to fire trigger after transaction commit in oracle

Tags: oracle, transactions, database-trigger

How can I make the trigger fired after transaction commit?

Ideally，the trigger will update data in Table2 when I insert data to Table1

Oracle Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger TB1_TRI 
    after update or delete or insert on Table1 
    for each row **update Table2**
```

Expected: If the insert transaction rollback, the trigger should not be fired.
Actual: The trigger is fired before the insert transaction commit and if the transaction rollback the trigger get no info.

Comment: You can't; a DML trigger is part of the same transaction of the firing DML (unless your trigger uses `pragma autonomous_transaction`, but that should very much be the exception). So, if you rollback the original transaction, the work done as part of the trigger will also be rolled back.

Comment: But that is the way how triggers are intended to work. If you rollback the data changed in the trigger will also be undone in the rollback unless you perform them in an autonomous transaction...

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your scenario in a bit more detail. Provide some sample inputs for `table1` then show what you expect in `table2` if the transaction is committed or rolled back. Maybe we can find a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Instead of update Table2, actually it will call a procedure which will call a Java class. the Java class will update mysql data . How can I control the transaction .

Comment: Use a procedure instead of a trigger. Inside the procedure you can control the transaction.